# How to write a JOIN for a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in need of functionality for getting the Country name from the IP.

I have to show the country in front of every unique visitor I have on my site. (Previously, I asked a question regarding a similar approach, but I changed it now.)

The output I expect would be something as follows:-

```
Country Visited | No. of Times
_______________________________
United States   |   482
Korea           |   213
Pakistan        |   123

....
```

The output is showing that 482 Unique visitors have come from US, 213 from Korea, and so on.

To achieve this, I divided this task into two part, first getting all the IPs of the Unique user and the second part is to search two tables with country/IP information to get the country.

We then aggregate data based on the top output table shown. I am going to show the queries I wrote for each part. Below, I have shown the Structure and Sample Data of the tables used.

### First Part - Getting Unique Visitors on my site

```
SELECT a.uid, a.hostname, COUNT( * ) AS times
FROM login_activity a
WHERE a.uid =83
GROUP BY a.hostname
ORDER BY times
```

This shows the output as below. It means that the USer with ID 83 has 80 unique visits to the site:

```
uid  | hostname         | times
-------------------------------------
83   |  157.191.122.36  | 80
```

This is wrong as I should be getting the no. of hits for each IP. But somehow I am unable to do so.

### Second Part - Finding the country based on IP

```
SELECT cc, cn
FROM ip
NATURAL JOIN cc
WHERE INET_ATON(  "157.191.122.36" ) 
BETWEEN START AND END
```

This gives me the output as:

```
cc | cn
--------
US | United States
```

This is correct, as it's giving me the correct Country based on the IP provided.

With the help of these three tables and two queries I've shown on top, I need to show the following result:

```
Country Visited | No. of Times
_______________________________
United States   |   482
Korea           |   213
Pakistan        |   123

....
```

### Appendix (Structure and Data of the Tables)

### **login_activity**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mslop_login_activity` (
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for an activity (session).',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The mslop_users.uid corresponding to a session, or 0 for anonymous user.',
  `host_user_agent` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '$_SERVER["HOST_USER_AGENT"] string. This can be used with get_browser() in PHP.',
  `hostname` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The IP address that was used for this session.',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The UNIX timestamp when the session was started.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`),
  KEY `aid` (`aid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

(Data)

```
INSERT INTO `mslop_login_activity` (`aid`, `uid`, `host_user_agent`, `hostname`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363038356),
(873, 4, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1369773601),
(883, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1369774959),
(893, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31', '157.191.122.36', 1369818602),
(903, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1369838690),
(913, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; AskTbORJ/5.15.23.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1369840224),
(923, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0', '157.191.122.36', 1369841748),
(933, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370255417),
(943, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1370258059),
(953, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1370258060),
(963, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1370299827),
(973, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1370299852),
(983, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299899),
(993, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299920),
(1003, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299995),
(1013, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319811),
(1023, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319835),
(1033, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319939),
(1043, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320312),
(1053, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320640),
(1063, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320713),
(1073, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370363702),
(1083, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370363987),
(1093, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370364021),
(1103, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370364028),
(1113, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370365896),
(1123, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370366087),
(1133, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370367070),
(1143, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370368567),
(1153, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370368575),
(1163, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370379345),
(1173, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370427302),
(1183, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)', '157.191.122.36', 1370503422),
(1193, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370534329),
(1203, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370866207),
(1213, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)', '157.191.122.36', 1370871353),
(1223, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/26.0.1410.43; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370877702),
(1233, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371015245),
(1243, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1371069245),
(1253, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371117509),
(1263, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371137716),
(1273, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1371197327),
(1283, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371427531),
(1293, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371552899),
(1303, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371635304),
(1313, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371770752),
(1323, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371771394),
(1333, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371771647),
(1343, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371772611),
(1353, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371772626),
(1363, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371772931),
(1373, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SIMBAR={37EF0ACB-CCB3-11E2-9611-E006E6BAE768}; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1371782438),
(1383, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371782562),
(1393, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371790767),
(1403, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371834780);
```

### **cc**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE cc (
        ci TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        cc CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        cn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        );
```

(Data)

Since it's large, you can download it through this link :-

http://d.pr/f/N3KT

### **ip**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE ip (
        start INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        end INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        ci TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        );
```

(Data)

Since it's large, you can download it through this link:-

http://d.pr/f/wcEy.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` in the first statement is invalid but MySQL does not reject it as every other DBMS - it simply chooses to return random data. Read this to understand why: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: Are you looking for unique visits or unique visitors?

Comment: Hi, Gordon, I am looking for Unique Visits and horse_with_no_name, Regarding Group By, I wanna use something else, if it works but with my puny knowledge, I seem to have less options.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query :

```
SELECT cn As 'Country Visited', count(0) AS 'No. of Times'
FROM mslop_login_activity a
INNER JOIN ip ON ( INET_ATON(a.hostname) BETWEEN START AND END )
NATURAL JOIN CC
GROUP BY cn
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I tried running the script with this IP 157.191.122.36, instead of INET_ATON(a.hostname) (as this IP address is the most common in the login_activity table) and the Query gave me United States | 208. I then added sample Netherlands IP of (5.10.88.12) as a test in the login_activity table and the right response should have been Netherlands | 3, but it gave me Netherlands | 280. So the number 280 is coming in regardless of the IP I put in. I'll be very thankful if you could help .... Thanks.

Comment: I've been trying to fix this but couldn't make it work ... I'll be very thankful if you can assist me in this ...

Comment: @Steve If you remove `a` from join condition all the rows from `a` will be returned because they are not correlated to `ip` anymore. If you want to test one ip only use `where a.hostname = '157.191.122.36'`.

Comment: Hi Nikola, I tried doing what you mentioned but to no avail. Probably, I've been doing it wrong. Do you mind writing the specific query after change? Many Many Thanks.

Comment: Any help guys, I'll highly appreciate.

Comment: My query + 
NATURAL JOIN CC
where a.hostname = '157.191.122.36'
GROUP BY cn